# PlayFramework: Get original request xml body as string

Tags: xml, scala, playframework

I'm receiving a request with an xml as body, the problem is that I've to read the original string that's inside the body.
This because there are some comments in the xml header that I've to read to detect the type of document.

As per play framework [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaXmlRequests) you've to tell play framework to parse the request body as xml

```
def sayHello = Action { request =>
  request.body.asXml.map { xml =>
    (xml \\ "name" headOption).map(_.text).map { name =>
      Ok("Hello " + name)
    }.getOrElse {
      BadRequest("Missing parameter [name]")
    }
  }.getOrElse {
    BadRequest("Expecting Xml data")
  }
}
```

that works fine, however, if I try to print `xml.toString` I don't get the original xml with the comments as they're outside the main xml element.

I've also tried to use `request.body.asText` but it checks the `Content-Type` header and since it's `application/xml` it doesn't return the string but instead it returns `None`

How can I extract the original body of the request as string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tolerantText` like

```
def save = Action(parse.tolerantText) { request =>
  Ok("Got: " + request.body)
}
```

> This one doesn’t check the Content-Type header and always loads the
>   request body as a String.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaBodyParsers

Comment: Is there an API to do that inline? (not in the action argument)? For now seems that `request.body.*` lacks asTolerantText

Comment: I never do that inline and did not meet in docs. I guess you can look into the play source code on the GitHub and get how `Action` process the request with the request body parser.

Comment: Too bad tolerantText doesn't use UTF-8 but ISO-8859-1  https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5334

Comment: it uses if it is specified. From the source code at     
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/ContentTypes.scala  `// Encoding notes: RFC-2616 section 3.7.1 mandates ISO-8859-1 as the default charset if none is specified.
        bytes.decodeString(request.charset.getOrElse("ISO-8859-1"))`